# Trouble loading in app purchases

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I implemented in app purchases in my iOS app a while ago and they worked well for a while, but now on iOS 9 they do not work. The price does not load and then when I click the button to make the purchase, I get an alert that says "No Internet Connection". My connection is fine and it should work.

I apologize for the extremely convoluted code. I wrote this early on when I started learning programming and haven't gotten around to cleaning it up a bit.

Implementation:
I have my product ids defined in my AppDelegate as so:

```
#define kRemoveAdsProductIdentifier @"0991"
#define kDoubleEarningRate @"199"
#define kQuadDogecoins @"399"
#define kMegaDogecoins @"1999"
#define kAll @"5991"

    kProductIdentifiers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:kRemoveAdsProductIdentifier, kDoubleEarningRate, kQuadDogecoins, kAll, kMegaDogecoins, nil];
```

In `IAPView.m`:

```
-(void)didLoadFromCCB
{
    AppController *app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    SKProductsRequest *productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc]initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithArray:app.kProductIdentifiers]];
    productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [productsRequest start];
}
```

When purchase button is clicked:

```
-(void)removeAds{
    if([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]){
        if (validProduct != nil) {
            NSLog(@"User can make payments");
            AppController *app = (AppController*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
            app.appProduct = validProduct;
            [app purchase:app.appProduct];
            NSLog(@"Product ID: %@", app.appProduct.productIdentifier);
        } else {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"No Internet Connection" message:@"You must be connected to the internet to purchase this product." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Continue" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }
    else{
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"You do not have the ability to make payments." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Continue" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

Product request:

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response{
    validProduct = nil;
    doubleEarningProduct = nil;
    quadrupleDogecoins = nil;
    allOfTheAbove = nil;
    megaDoge = nil;
    NSInteger count = [response.products count];
    NSLog(@"Products.count = %li", (long)count);
    if(count > 0){
        validProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];
        doubleEarningProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:1];
        quadrupleDogecoins = [response.products objectAtIndex:3];
        megaDoge = [response.products objectAtIndex:2];
        allOfTheAbove = [response.products objectAtIndex:4];

        _numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [_numberFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
        [_numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
        [_numberFormatter setLocale:validProduct.priceLocale];
        NSString *formattedPrice = [_numberFormatter stringFromNumber:validProduct.price];
        formattedStringFinal = formattedPrice;
        [adsPrice setString:formattedPrice];

        formattedPrice = [_numberFormatter stringFromNumber:doubleEarningProduct.price];
        formattedStringFinal = formattedPrice;
        [doubleEarningLabel setString:formattedPrice];

        formattedPrice = [_numberFormatter stringFromNumber:quadrupleDogecoins.price];
        formattedStringFinal = formattedPrice;
        [quadDogeLabel setString:formattedPrice];

        formattedPrice = [_numberFormatter stringFromNumber:allOfTheAbove.price];
        formattedStringFinal = formattedPrice;
        [aboveLabel setString:formattedPrice];

        formattedPrice = [_numberFormatter stringFromNumber:megaDoge.price];
        formattedStringFinal = formattedPrice;
        [megaDogeLabel setString:formattedPrice];

    }
    else if(!validProduct){
        NSLog(@"No products available");
    }
}
```

For some reason `count` gets output as 0. I got the feeling that it might be due to an error with provisioning profiles, and sure enough my provisioning profile for IAP was expired. I updated it and added it to XCode but the prices still do not load.

It works perfectly fine on my iPad (iOS 8.1), but not not on my iPhone (iOS 9).

Any ideas?

Comment: `added it to XCode` - So this isn't an app that's in the App Store or anything, these are problems that are just happening in development?

Comment: It is on the App Store, I was under the notion that I had to regenerate the provisioning profile and click it to "Add it to xcode"

Comment: Seems to be a problem with iOS 9. It works fine on iOS 8.1